# Possible to build Blender with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: blender, visual-studio-2012

Currently the latest Blender C/C++ project builds with Visual Studio 2008.

Has anyone succeeded in building it with Visual Studio 2012 / MSVC11?

Thanks!! :)